# How to undo a seeding action? Laravel5

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel-5, laravel-seeding

I have run this seeder:

```
private function seedUsers()
{
    $users = [
        [
            'name'       => '**',
            'email'      => 'admin@**.com',
            'gender'     => '**',
            'privacy'    => '**',
            'password'    => '**',
            'country_id' => *,
            'city_id'    => *,
            'role_id'    => *,
        ],
    ];
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        factory(App\Services\Users\User::class)->create($user);
    }
    factory(App\Services\Users\User::class, 10)->create();// This line was included by mistake.
}
```

Is there away to to undo this seeder and re-run it after I have removed the line that adds 10 test users?

I'm using Laravel5.5

Bear in mind, I have these users' email addresses and that this is not a testing DB, so I need to only remove these 10 test users.

Comment: use this command : php artisan migrate:refresh --seed

Comment: No, this is on prod. but thnx.

Comment: unfortunately i think there's nothing native on laravel about that. You'll have to install a package like [undo-seeder](https://github.com/killmenot/undo-seeder-laravel) but you have to install it before to keep track or do a "manual rollback" by removing everything your seeder generated.

Answer (score 0):

use Undo Seeder for Laravel.

When you install UndoSeeder, the following artisan commands are made available:

- db:seed-undo -> Undo seeds in the seeds directory.
- db:seed-refresh -> Undo seeds run seeds again.